# Difficulty to copy a char * in an unsigned char (struct element)

Tags: c, struct, casting

I don't find any solutions to my problem, I think it's easy, but not for me.
My second `strcpy` doesn't work, how can I put `word2` in `var2`?

```
/* struct */
struct StructName {
    char var1[15];
    unsigned char var2;
};
/*main*/
int main(void) {
    char *word1;
    char *word2;
    struct StructName Name;
    char line[] = "abc=12 xxxxxxxxx";
    word1 = strtok(line, " "); 
    word1 = strtok(word1, "=");
    word2 = strtok(NULL, "=");
    if ((strcmp(word1, "abc"))==0) {
        strcpy(Name.var1, word1);
        printf("%s", Name.var1);
        strcpy(Name.var2,(unsigned char)word2);
        printf("%d", Name.var2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: However I think about it, it is a bad idea to put a pointer into a character.

Comment: What are you doing in the 3rd line of `main(void)`? It looks like you're trying to create a struct named `Name` that is identical to the struct `StructName`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @GabrieleB-David OP is just declaring a variable called `Name` that has type `struct StructName`. In C you have to keep the `struct` attached like that unless you `typedef` it away, which the OP has not done.

Comment: @yano thank you for clarifying that. Didn't notice that the OP didn't use `typedef`.

Comment: For one, you cannot put a string (multiple characters) in `unsigned char word2` because it is a single character. The line `strcpy(Name.var2,(unsigned char)word2);` does not even compile for me.

Comment: @GabrieleB-David that is very basic in C. Struct deceleration  can be done like  that if it is global then it's scope is for entire module.  Or you can struct forward also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of the function `int atoi(const char*)` in stdlib.h? Try using that to convert your string to an int, and then convert that int into an unsigned char.

Edit: Only do this if you're trying to extract the number 12 from `line`, which is what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: You mean the OP wants to fetch the number 12 from the string and store that in var2? I'm not even sure that's what they're trying to do; the question is not clear as to what they're trying to achieve. This is a good guess though.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, however if you want to convert word2 to Name.var2, you can follow following steps.
Firstly you can convert char pointer to int, then behave address of integer number as an unsigned char pointer.

```
/*main*/
int main(void) {
    char *word1;
    char *word2;
    int number = 0;
    struct StructName Name;
    char line[] = "abc=12 xxxxxxxxx";
    word1 = strtok(line, " "); 
    word1 = strtok(word1, "=");
    word2 = strtok(NULL, "=");
    if ((strcmp(word1, "abc"))==0) {
        strcpy(Name.var1, word1);
        printf("%s", Name.var1);
        number = atoi(word2);
        Name.var2 = *(unsigned char*)&number;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Include stdlib library for atoi function. Unsigned char size and integer size are not match. Thus, your input should compatible with char size.

Comment: Why are you putting the value in an int, taking its address, converting it to a char* and then dereferencing it? That seems like a convoluted way to put the number in var2. Not to mention all kinds of conversion problems such as when it's big-endian.

Answer (score 0):

Yes my objective is to copy the Number 12 in an unsigned char.
function atoi works well,
I try this an it's seems works.

```
if ((strcmp(word1, "abc"))==0) {
    strcpy(Name.var1, word1);
    printf("%s", Name.var1);
    Name.var2=(unsigned char)atoi(word2);
    printf("%d", Name.var2);
}
```

Their is difference with Gürtaç Kadem proposition?

Thanks again!
Brodbeni

Comment: If this is the solution for you, you may want to accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left. That way, the question will no longer show up under unsolved questions.

Answer (score -1):

Olaf thinks it is a bad idea to put a pointer into a character, well, it would be a very good idea if it worked - it would save a lot of memory.

Unfortunately, it won't work.  It's point(er)less and, in any case, will not fit unless yur CPU has only 256 bytes of RAM or less:(

Comment: C does not require `CHAR_BIT` to be eight.

Comment: OK, maybe I should have stuck to 'it's a gross type mismatch' :)

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Just say `pow(2,CHAR_BIT)` and be done with it.

Comment: @MrLister: No need to bring floating-point math into this. Just use `1u << CHAR_BIT`, provided `UINT_MAX > UCHAR_MAX`, otherwise `1ul << CHAR_BIT` if `ULONG_MAX > UCHAR_MAX` otherwise `1ull << CHAR_BIT` if `ULLONG_MAX > UCHAR_MAX`, otherwise you may indeed need floating-point.

Comment: @EOF Sorry for not providing the same smiley as Thingy did :)